# Convert string to single digits and sum

Tags: r, text, recursion, sum, character

I've tried for hours to find a solution to what I thought was an easy task but I failed.

I have a string consisting of 3 different characters `('I','R' & 'O')` with length from 1 to 6.
E.g

```
IRRROO
RRORRR
IIR
RIRRO
```

Each character represents a number `I=1,R=2,O=3`
I need to convert this string to a single number, multiply with position and sum the result. E.g

```
IRRROO ---> (1*1)+(2*2)+(2*3)+(2*4)+(3*5)+(3*6) =52
IIR    ---> (1*1)+(1*2)+(2*3) =9
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

factors have numeric equivalents.  You can leverage that nicely for this example:

```
# original
x1 <- "IRRROO"

         # 1    2    3
levs <- c("I", "R", "O")

# split the string and convert to factors, then to numeric
x1f <- as.numeric(factor(strsplit(x1, "")[[1]], levels=levs))

# tally it up 
sum(x1f * seq_along(x1f))
```

#### Or as a nice, single-line function:

```
sumValue <- function(x, levs=c("I", "R", "O")) 
    sum(seq.int(nchar(x)) *  as.numeric(factor(strsplit(x, "")[[1]], levels=levs)))

sumValue("IRRROO")
# [1] 52
sumValue("IIR")
# [1] 9
```

Comment: Great answer! I learned one or two things just by viewing this question. Thank you.

Comment: Would this be generalisable to setting the letters to non-consecutive values? - e.g. `I=4,R=10,O=11`

Comment: @thelatemail, no of course not. In such a case you either need dummy factor levels or you just use dictionary indexing as in your answer ;)

Answer (score 7):

Alternative version using a named vector as input, allowing arbitrary numeric value assignment to each letter:

```
vals <- c(I=1,R=2,O=3)
test <- c("IRRROO","RRORRR","IIR","RIRRO")

sumValue <- function(dat,vals) {
  tmp <- strsplit(dat,"")
  vapply(tmp,function(x) sum(seq_along(x) * vals[x]),numeric(1))
}

sumValue(test,vals)
[1] 52 45  9 33
```

Comment: replacing `sapply(...)` with `vapply(.., 0)` significantly improves the speed.