# How to assign numbers to words in text statements and then add them in r?

Tags: r, sum, assign

I have a csv file with a column named text like the following and would like to assign numbers to certain words and then add them.

```
text
I have apples oranges and mangos.
I like cats.
sports and exercise.
```

I've created a matrix called matrix_values with following values.

```
     [,1]     [,2]
[1,] "apples" "1" 
[2,] "mangos" "3" 
[3,] "sports" "78"
```

Below is the code I have.

```
data <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

values <- c('apples', 'mangos', 'sports', 1,3,78)

matrix_values = matrix(values,nrow =3, ncol = 2)
```

The output should look like this

```
text,                                Value
I have apples oranges and mangos,    4
I like cats,                         0
sports and exercise,                 78
```

Notice how the values from the matrix adds the value for apples and mangos and treats the other words with a value of 0.

How do I do this?

Comment: Similar logic used here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15893737/convert-string-to-single-digits-and-sum/15893881

Answer (score 5):

If you `strsplit` your sentence up, you can then `match` to your `l`oo`kup` table and `sum`.

```
x <- c(
  "I have apples oranges and mangos.",
  "I like cats.",
  "sports and exercise."
)

lkup <-  data.frame(
  word = c("apples", "mangos", "sports"),
  value = c(1, 3, 78) 
)

vapply(
  strsplit(x, "\\s+|[.,]+"),
  function(x) sum(lkup$value[match(x,lkup$word)], na.rm=TRUE),
  FUN.VALUE = numeric(1)
)
#[1]  4  0 78
```

To explain the regex more:

```
\\s+     whitespace, repeated 1 or more times
|        OR
[.,]+    a period `.` or comma `,` repeated 1 or more times
```

Comment: Could you please explain your regex here?

Comment: @thelatemail I get an Error in strsplit(x, "\\s+|[.,]+") : non-character argument. If I change the list type of the csv into a character type it gives wrong output. below is my current code. x <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

x =as.character(x)

lkup <-  data.frame(
  word = c("apples", "mangos", "sports"),
  value = c(1, 3, 78) 
)

vapply(
  strsplit(x, "\\s+|[.,]+"),
  function(x) sum(lkup$value[match(x,lkup$word)], na.rm=TRUE),
  FUN.VALUE = numeric(1)
)

Comment: @Liu x is a data.frame, not a character vector , after you use read.csv. You need to select the column like x$text to use it, making sure you convert to character if necessary.

Comment: @thelatemail sorry had a typo in my code. It works now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way with `dplyr` and `stringr`. Note that this uses a `cross-join` so may have problems if your datasets are very large. -

```
df %>% 
  mutate(cj = 1) %>% 
  inner_join(mutate(lkup, cj = 1), by = "cj") %>% 
  mutate(test = str_detect(text, word)) %>% 
  group_by(text) %>% 
  summarize(value = sum(value*test))

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  text                              value
  <chr>                             <dbl>
1 I have apples oranges and mangos.     4
2 I like cats.                          0
3 sports and exercise.                 78
```

Data (thanks to @thelatemail) -

```
df <- read.table(text = "text
I have apples oranges and mangos.
I like cats.
sports and exercise.", header= T, stringsAsFactors = F, sep = "\t")    

lkup <-  tibble(
  word = c("apples", "mangos", "sports"),
  value = c(1, 3, 78) 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach which is kind of similar to @Shree but separating every word into `separate_rows`. Using @thelatemail's regex to separate them

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(row = row_number(), 
         text1 = text) %>%
  tidyr::separate_rows(text, sep = "\\s+|[.,]+") %>%
  left_join(lkup, by = c("text" = "word")) %>%
  group_by(row) %>%
  summarise(text = first(text1),
            value = sum(value, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
  select(-row)

#  text                              value
#  <fct>                             <dbl>
#1 I have apples oranges and mangos.     4
#2 I like cats.                          0
#3 sports and exercise.                 78
```